# Clear auto-complete input text-box cache on IE 10 on a jsp page

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer, spring-mvc, autocomplete, internet-explorer-10

I have a text box on a jsp page which shows suggestions of values (from the database) for auto-completion. And then I open a page corresponding to the value entered in the text box.
The problem happens on IE 10 (not on firefox or chrome), that once I enter a value, it opens the corresponding page, then if I delete the value from the database and again start entering a few initials of the same value, it shows it in the auto-complete suggestions list (only on IE 10, does not show on chrome and firefox). If I clean the temporary internet files manually, it works fine on IE 10 too.
 How do I solve this problem through my jsp code?

Answer (score 0):

From your jsp code, dynamically add the script below:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(":text").attr("autocomplete", "off");
    });
</script>
```